# jquery silky smooth marquee, pause it only when hover takes place on the anchor , not on the div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, marquee

I am using [this](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)  jquery plugin namely 'The Silky Smooth Marquee'for creating a marquee.

HTML

```
<div class="news_marquee">

<a href="1.php">aaaaa</a>  <a href="2.php">bbbb</a>  <a href="3.php">ccc</a>

</div>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
$('.news_marquee').marquee().mouseover(function () {
  $(this).trigger('stop');
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).trigger('start');
});
```

As a result , placing the cursor on the marquee `div` pauses it, but I want to pause  it only when the cursor is on the `a` tag inside the `news_marque` class;

I tried with the following code

```
    $('.news_marquee').marquee();
    $('.news_marquee a').mouseover(function () {
    $('.news_marquee').trigger('stop');
    }).mouseout(function () {
    $('.news_marquee').trigger('start');
    });
```

but that does not work.

How to achieve what I desire ?

**EDIT:** When the left to right marquee starts , then it takes time for the marquee to reach the left end and during that time if mouse is placed on the blank space next to the left end , the marquee is paused but I want to pause it only when the mouse is on the `a` tag i.e. placing cursor on the blank space should not pause it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
$('.news_marquee a').marquee().mouseover(function () {
  $('.news_marquee').trigger('stop');
}).mouseout(function () {
  $('.news_marquee').trigger('start');
});
```

Comment: tried with it , but it does not do that. it should create so many marquees, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the target property combined with the Jquery is method(http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
$('.news_marquee').mouseover(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        // Hovers anchor tag!
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not work, chained `mouseover` with `marquee()` and used the target property to make it work. Added my answer

Comment: Wanted to show a technique that worked, but forgot the marquee. Sorry. Glad that it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

took help from Johan Sunden's answer and found the solution in this way :

```
$('.news_marquee').marquee().mouseover(function (e) {

    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {

$(this).trigger('stop');    
    }

}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).trigger('start');
});
```

**EDIT:** corrected the previously pasted code snippet